# Saving scores correctly and efficiently

Tags: android

This question gets thrown around here a lot. However, my side of the implementation is buggy, so it would help if you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance. Sorry if this question is so noob-like.

I develop [Court Counter, which can be found here.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ideaman924.courtcounter) I recently started to add saving support for my app. However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. All other stack overflow topics mention Editor, however Android Studio corrects me to SharedPreferences.Editor. I'm assuming this changed as of Marshmallow or whatever.

Anyway, I added these lines of code for saving and loading:

```
/**
 * Saves your current session
 * SharedPreferences key = courtCounter
 * team A key = teamA
 * team B key = teamB
 */

public void saveSession(View v) {
    //We will get saved preferences!
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("courtCounter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("teamA",scoreA);
    editor.putInt("teamB",scoreB);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Loads previous session
 * The config is same as saveSession
 */
public void loadSession(View v) {
    //We will get the preferences!
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("courtCounter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    scoreA = prefs.getInt("teamA", 0);
    scoreB = prefs.getInt("teamB", 0);
}
```

saveSession is called when the score gets updated, which you can see below:

```
/**
 * New way of adding score
 *
 * @param score Score that you need to add to the team
 * @param team  Team that you want the score added to
 * @param last  Last clicked item, for example, a1. This will be used for the undo action.
 */
public void scoreAdd(int score, char team, String last) {
    Button undo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.undo_button);
    undo.setEnabled(true);
    lastClicked = last;
    if (team == 'a') {
        scoreA += score;
        displayScore(scoreA, 'a');
    }
    if (team == 'b') {
        scoreB += score;
        displayScore(scoreB, 'b');
    }
    saveSession();
}
```

However, this throws an error, saying that I didn't supply a (view) or whatever in the brackets. How can I fix this? I don't need any input handlers, but Android Studio would freak out if I didn't make one.

Right now, the code works fine over here:

```
public void resetAll(View view) {
    Button undo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.undo_button);
    undo.setEnabled(false);
    lastClicked = "reset";
    scoreA = 0;
    scoreB = 0;
    displayScore(scoreA, 'a');
    displayScore(scoreB, 'b');
    saveSession(view);
}
```

I'm assuming this is because the resetAll has a view input parameter. However, resetAll is called from an onClick.

Other places where code does not work include the onCreate.

Any ideas?

Comment: if am not wrong you want to call your resetAll(View v) programmatically ?

Comment: No, I was asking how not to pass in the view. Android Studio will just blow if I remove (View v) from saveSession and loadSession.

Comment: Should I change void to class in front of save/loadSession? EDIT: I tried, and it errors out. Oh well.

Comment: one more question why do you want to remove (View v) from that method as its a button click listeners ?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. resetAll is tied to an onClick. save/loadSession is not. It gets called from resetAll, scoreAdd, and onCreate. So I would like to remove (view v) from save/loadSession, however Android Studio throws errors if I do so.

Comment: ohh, then show me the error man.

Comment: It says "; expected" where (View v) used to be. I don't want a ; in there because that would indicate that it's not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your saveSession is not even using the View v within the method, why are you making it as a parameter? Remove it.

```
public void saveSession() {
...
}

public void resetAll(View view) {
...
saveSession(); // I remove the view here.
}
```

You have a lot of unnecessary params, unnecessary since your method doesn't even use it.

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answer. Android Studio kept giving me errors if I removed it... then I realized I was typing too fast and Studio couldn't keep up. WTF, I'm on an i5. Whatever. Thanks again!

Comment: Remember that if your method doesn't use parameter, do not include it. If you include it, as update progress, your code will be unreadable and not efficient.

Comment: I know, I just thought Android Studio needed all these params because it would just go awry if I didn't include them. But then I realized it was because AS couldn't keep up. I'm going to do a bunch of code optimizations sometime, just can't do it right now.